# Asynchronous motor joule loss calculation

Tags: power, motor, ac

I'm wondering if this is the right place to ask my question, but i hope to get the answer.
How I can calculate the Joule loss with just those indication
output and input power, voltage, current, and rotor resistance.
I know that Pjr = g*Ptr
where Pjr : Joule loss on the rotor
g : sliding
Ptr : transmitted power (Ptr = Pa - Pjs - Pfs)
Pjs : joule loss on the stator
Pfs : iron loss on the stator
Pa : input power.
sorry for my bad language because i study in france

Comment: If you have input (rotor) current and rotor resistance you have joule loss in the rotor windings. Ultimately iron losses, mechanical and windage losses are also joule losses (energy lost as heat) so it comes down to knowing the exact terminology used in your course.

Answer (score 1):

If you know only the input power, output power, voltage, current and rotor resistance, you can not calculate the total joule loss. You can calculate the total losses, but that includes joule losses plus iron losses plus mechanical losses plus stray load losses. Output power is the power transmitted to the rotor minus rotor joule losses minus mechanical losses. I assume that input power is Pa. I assume g is slip and g = (synchronous speed minus operating speed) divided by synchronous speed. The relationships that you state seem to be correct. In some circumstances, you might neglect some losses, but I don't think that it is reasonable to assume that you should neglect everything except rotor joule losses. You could assume some typical relationship among the losses, but that doesn't seem very reasonable either. Are you sure that you have stated everything that you know about this problem?

Edit 1

The stator and rotor leakage (series) reactances are apparently null in comparison to the resistance, and the resistance of the magnetizing reactance is also very small. That means that you can assume that the reactive component of the input current flows only through the magnetizing reactance and the real component is current in one phase of the rotor. The equivalent circuit sets the ratio of stator to rotor winding turns at 1:1 and adjusts the rotor resistance accordingly. Since the motor is wound-rotor rather than squirrel-cage, the rotor resistance is high even with the rings short-circuited.

Comment: * output power: 11 kW;
* speed N = 2850 tr/min;
* voltage : U = 380 V; 50 Hz;
* current : I = 21,44 A;
* yield (out/in power) : η = 0,90;
* stator in star connection;
* rotor in  star connection, resistance of a phase : r = 0,05 Ω.
Pm = Pjs = 0.
7.1. rotor shorted:
• input power ;
• cosϕ and ϕ;
• reactive power Q ;
• the electromagnetic torque Te ;
• sliding g ;
• Pjr
• the current in one phase of the rotor.
7.2. Calculate the iron losses of the stator and the corresponding component of the current drawn If.

Comment: what i need is joul losses on the rotor, the current in one phase of the rotor, iron losses

Comment: I don't understand "Pm = Pj =0. 7.1." Do you know the values of any of "input power ; • cosϕ and ϕ; • reactive power Q ; • the electromagnetic torque Te ;" I don't understand "the current in one phase of the rotor. 7.2." Rater than adding information as a comment, it is better to revise the question. It would help to list given data under a heading, assumptions under another heading, calculated items thus far under a heading, items needing calculation under a heading all in separate paragraphs.

Comment: Guidelines for school problem assistance at this site require you to show or describe your effort and progress on solving the problem yourself. Tomorrow, I can try to suggest more about how to proceed. Tonight, I am not feeling very well.

Comment: Mécanicien losses and joules losses on the stator are null. 7.1 is the quastion number and I have solved the following questions : input power. Cos phi and phi. Reactive power electromagnetic torque slip g. Then I am confused how do I can calculate the joules losses on the rotor

Comment: Me too I don't understand how to calculate the current in one phase of the rotor.